# Laravel schedule: creating new row in a table automatically

Tags: laravel, schedule

(Laravel framework) I'm trying to create new row automatically in a table using schedule inside the handle function  but it's not adding the row to the table:

```
public function handle()
{
    Reserved::create([
              'book_id'=>1,
              'user_id'=>1
    ]);
}
```

the schedule is working when I try other things like deleting a row or sending emails...
What can I do?

Comment: There might be errors in the log. If this is your actual code then maybe it's in violation of some unique constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't added the `$fillable` property to your `Reserved` model class. This prevents the create method from storing a new instance.

See Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Also, Laravel stores log files under storage/logs. Have you looked if there is any error message logged?

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me about the stores log files! The error was it didn't find the model because I misspelled in the use.